# Can I express the inequalities $x+y \geq 3$ and $x+y \leq 4$ in a single inequality?

Tags: inequality

Trying to specify the domain and range for a function and it needs to be between these two values, is this the best way to specify it? Thanks

Comment: $3 \le x+y \le 4$

Comment: $|x+y-3.5|\leq 0.5$

Comment: Um... yes.   If $M \ge j$ and $M \le k$ we can write $j \le M \le k$.  So we can write $3\le x+y \le 4$

Comment: Another one: $$(x+y-3.5)^2 \le 0.25$$

Comment: Or: $(x+y-3)(x+y-4)\leq 0$.